# Calling stored procedure using EF with selected input parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to call a Stored procedure that has 20 input parameters. I want to pass in only 4 which are appropriate. How do I explicitly add the only 4 input parameters? The function import object expects all parameters.

Something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rmi_src_id", medication.RmiSourceId.Value);
```

However I do not want to use SQLCommnand but achieve this through EF object.

Comment: What is the name of your stored Procedure

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>("EXEC YourStoredProcedureName @rmi_src_id", medication.RmiSourceId.Value);
```

`Build all your 20 Params, And Values following the same Example posted above`

Here is some additional Documentation you may want to Reference as well
[Define a Model with a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx)

Comment: Since its a Stored proce is <TEntity> valid. It does not recoginize TEntity.

Comment: This link will totally help you understand my example `TEntity` gets replaced with what ever your `Entity Object for example Person` is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx